# Trigger a job from Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I would like to know how to create a task scheduler job from powershell for the following scenario.

The script runs between the hours of 6 AM and 9 PM Monday through Friday where the script will terminate if it runs longer than 30 minutes.

I have tried

```
$adminname=''
$adminpassword=''
$taskName = ""
$L = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument ''
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 06:30Pm -DaysOfWeek 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday','Friday' 
$P = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "" -LogonType Password -RunLevel Highest
$S = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $L -Trigger $T -User $adminname -Password $adminpassword -Settings $S
$task = get-scheduledtask -TaskName $taskName
$task.Triggers.repetition.Interval = 'PT15M'
$task | Set-ScheduledTask -User $adminname -Password $adminpassword
```

The above code schedules the job from monday to friday. But could not get a way to apply the time stamp i.e to be run between  6AM to 9PM

I have tried adding `$task.Triggers.ExecutionTimeLimit = 'PT30M` for terminating job if it runs longer than 30 minutes. But its giving `The property 'ExecutionTimeLimit' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.` error

Comment: Show what you have tried. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, and you haven't given enough information for people to write it for you in the first place.

Comment: Why not create the task manually and export config as XML? Then you can re-create the task from said XML file.

Comment: @alroc added the code which i tried

Comment: @vonPryz is it possible to create task scheduler job from powershell using the exported xml file?

Comment: You haven't provided enough of the required parameters for that cmdlet.

Comment: @alroc can u tell me how to terminate the job if it runs longer than 10 minutes.

Comment: @Venkatakrishnan Have you [done your homework](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and researched the topic with, say, a Google search? Task Sceduler's XML files are well-documented feature.

Comment: @vonPryz i have done enough google searches. if you could help it will be much appreciated

Comment: This question is terrible, primarily for the reason that the question title is generic and does not specifically identify the desired behavior.

Comment: Question isn't terrible.. The topic may be generic.... This site is meant for helping each other. Not to pin point the mistakes alone.. If you cannot help, its ok .. other will help..

Answer (score 1):

New-ScheduledTaskAction : Sets What you want to run

New-ScheduledTaskTrigger : Set How often and when to start the run

Register-ScheduledTask : Create the Task

[TASK].Triggers.Repetition.Duration : How long the task time should run from start time

[TASK].Triggers.Repetition.Interval : How long the task should run before its killed

{PK means Pickup Time, Use PK for H(hours) M(Minutes) use P for Pickup for D(Days) Ex PK15H, P5D}

[TASK] | Set-ScheduledTask : Enable Task

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute Powershell.exe
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -At 6:30AM -DaysOfWeek 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday' 
$task = Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TESTTASK" -Trigger $trigger -Action $action -RunLevel Highest
$task.Triggers.Repetition.Duration = "PT15H" 
$task.Triggers.Repetition.Interval = "PT15M"
$task | Set-ScheduledTask -User "USERNAME" -Password "PASSWORD"
```

Comment: Thank for the info. can u tell me how to  terminate the job if it runs longer than 10 minutes.

Comment: $task.Triggers.Repetition.Interval = "PT10M"

Comment: that is for triggering interval. I am asking about terminating the job instance if it runs longer than 30 minutes.